# DTD - definition or description?

Tags: dtd, xml

I've come across "Document Type Defintion" and "Document Type Description" for the meaning of DTD, such as DocBook DTD. Are they interchangable or is one incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description and definition in this case are related like this:

```
Definition > Description
```

In other words, by defining it you're describing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Both the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) and ISO 8879 (which defines SGML, on which XML is based) gloss "DTD" as an acronym for "document type definition".  Both specs also use the term "document type declaration" to denote the syntactic construct by which a document points to its document type definition.  (And as a result, there is often some uncertainty about whether DTD might mean "document type declaration" instead.)

If your sources are trying to reflect the usage of the SGML and XML specifications, you now know which of them are correct.  Of course, they may not be trying to do any such thing.